# Creating a batch file for the command

Tags: batch-file

How to put the below command in a batch file format. I need the whole batch file that runs that command

```
schtasks /change /tn "Calculator" /ENABLE
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Open `Notepad` from the start menu. Copy that line of code from your question here, and paste it into the blank document in `Notepad`. Use `File->Save As` from the menu, save the file as `YourBatchFileName.bat`. Close `Notepad`. You now have the command in a batch file.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about saving a simple text (batch) file on the computer, not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198865/getting-into-a-batch-script-the-command-to-enable-the-scheduled-task

Answer (score 1):

On the top right there is a search bar it is you friend use it type `command to enable the scheduled task` **top result !!!**